# Argument type mismatch using nifi template import API

Tags: rest, exception, apache-nifi

I am trying to use the import endpoint of the [Nifi REST API 1.0](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/). I have exported a template as XML using the UI, and am trying to import it using Postman. The request looks like this:

```
POST /nifi-api/process-groups/63dcaf98-0158-1000-04da-dd54bbb3a5b8/templates/import HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 37a10e8b-b30d-b5c8-4219-ca1ba34f79da

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template encoding-version="1.0">
   <description></description>
   ...
</template>
```

I get `400` error return, with message `argument type mismatch`. There's nothing very useful in the nifi-user.log:

```
2016-11-14 14:58:22,164 INFO [NiFi Web Server-327] org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for (anonymous)     POST http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/63dcaf98-0158-1000-04da-dd54bbb3a5b8/templates/import (source ip: 127.0.0.1)
 2016-11-14 14:58:22,231 INFO [NiFi Web Server-327] o.a.n.w.a.c.IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch. Returning Bad Request response.
```

Any ideas what may be causing this, or how I can debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the root `template` element with another element called `templateEntity`. Most endpoints in Apache NiFi 1.0.0 wrap the object in question with an `entity` object to relay relevant details about the object when access is denied for to help promote the multi-tenancy model. This pattern was applied to most endpoints to help with consistency throughout the API.

Also you can get to additional details by enabling debug level logging for

```
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.web.api.config" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
```

in conf/logback.xml.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to upload the template, with the following command ( I use curl):

curl -iv -F template=@Sample_Process_group.xml -X POST  http://172.17.0.4:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/2a9c6a0d-015c-1000-dec6-e81122344f7e/templates/upload where the guid is your root Process Group.